# Spliting a text file's contents based on repetitive line values

Tags: linux, split, text-processing

I have a single-column text file like:

A.txt

```
0;
1;
2;
3;
.
.
.
0;
4;
8;
.
.
.
0;
6;
9;
```

The goal is to split A.txt into files based on the line's values in a way that for each line value that is seen more than once in A.txt, there must be a separate split based on that. Here is an example of the desired output files assuming that "0;" is the only repetitive element inside A.txt:

A1.txt

```
0;
1;
2;
3;
.
.
.
```

A2.txt

```
0;
4;
8;
.
.
.
```

A3.txt

```
0;
6;
9;
.
.
.
```

any idea how to that through linux bash scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = <>;
chomp @lines;

my %count;
$count{$_}++ for @lines;

my $OUT;
my $x;
for my $separator (grep $count{$_} > 1, keys %count) {
    for my $line (@lines) {
        open $OUT, '>', 'A' . ++$x . '.txt' or die $!
            if not $OUT or $separator eq $line;
        print {$OUT} "$line\n";
    }
    undef $OUT;
}
```

Comment: Generates a single text file with the same content as A.txt!

Comment: Can you please try it on a file having lines with different lengths?

Comment: It splits on lines containing only `0;`. Is it what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, it was just an example of what I need. I need to do split the file based on line values seen more than once. In my example I have assumed that 0; is the only non-distinct line value which is repeatedly seen in A.txt

Comment: @user3403765: Will there always be only one such a line?

Comment: not necessarily. But the split must be done for each of repetitive value separately. For example if both 0; and 2; are repetitive values in A.txt the split of A.txt must be done twice separately based on each of them.

Comment: @user3403765: How large is the input file?

Comment: hundred thousands of lines